# How can I count frequency of words separated by ";" in each row-column across the data.frame (See image)?

Tags: r, dataframe, bioinformatics

INPUT: `data.frame':  5803 obs. of  23 variables:`

| Clusters | Representative | Genome1 | Genome2 | GenomeX |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Gene family 1 | Locus1;Locus2;Locus3 | Locus1;Locus2 | Locus1 |
| 2 | Gene family 1 | Locus2;Locus3 | Locus2;Locus3 | (blank) |

I want to convert to a count table with the number of occurrence in each cell ( NAs counted as 0).

OUTPUT:

| Clusters | Representative | Genome1 | Genome2 | GenomeX |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Gene family 1 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | Gene family 1 | 2 | 2 | 0 |

Answer (score 0):

You can (at least in the example data) count the number of `;` separators in each cell and add 1 to that value.

If empty cells are not NA but the actual string '(blank)' change the condition to `. == '(blank)'`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with('Genome'), ~ ifelse(is.na(.), 0, stringr::str_count(., ';') + 1)))

#> # A tibble: 2 × 5
#>   Clusters Representative Genome1 Genome2 GenomeX
#>      <dbl> <chr>            <int>   <int>   <int>
#> 1        1 Gene family 1        3       2       1
#> 2        2 Gene family 1        2       2       0
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The "locus" was an example. The gene loci are named differently in different columns. For e.g. One column as EFDACLK_01039;JEFDACLK_01054;JEFDACLK_01435. 
The second column has LELKMIGK_01090;LELKMIGK_00114;LELKMIGK_00131
Sorry for not uploading the image, I thought I did but turns out I didn't.

Comment: @sdas See the updated answer